# Is there a way i can search in a list for some letters of a word and delete the whole word?(SOLVED)

Tags: python, list

im trying to code a simple contact book with just names and phone numbers. I want it to have the options add,remove,search and exit obviously. In my remove and search option i got one problem: For example if the use adds a new name to the contact book for example "Alex Balex" and wants to remove it or search it after he needs to type Alex Balex but i want the program to find and delete Alex out of the list if i search for "Alex Bal" aswell. That was my attempt but i cant find a solution:

import pickle
import sys
while True:

```
option = int(input(("You got 3 options 1=add 2=remove 3=search 4=exit and save. Please enter what you want to do: ")))
if option == 1:
    names = []
    names = pickle.load(open("names.dat", "rb"))

    new_entry, new_number = str(input("Enter a new name which you want to be added to the CB in this format name:phone_number\nINPUT: ")).split(":")
    new_user = "Name: " + new_entry + "         Number: " + new_number
    names.append(new_user)
    pickle.dump(names, open("names.dat", "wb"))
elif option == 2:
    names = []
    names = pickle.load(open("names.dat", "rb"))
    print(names)
    new_removal = str(input("Enter what you want to remove: "))
    for element in names:
        if new_removal in element:
            names.remove(names[names.index(element)])
    pickle.dump(names, open("names.dat", "wb"))
elif option == 4:
    sys.exit()

elif option == 3:
    names = []
    names = pickle.load(open("names.dat", "rb"))
    print(names)
    new_search = str(input("Search either a name or a number: "))
    for element in names:
        if new_search in element:
            new_search = names[names.index(element)]
            print(new_search)
    pickle.dump(names, open("names.dat", "wb"))
```

Comment: User `input`, `pickle`, and options are irrelevant to this question. See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to your problem is to find the first name with the prefix the user entered, and then remove that:

```py
elif option == 2:
    new_removal = str(input("Enter what you want to remove: "))
    i_remove = -1
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        if name.lower()[0:len(new_removal)] == new_removal.lower():
            i_remove = i
            break
    if i_remove != -1:
        names.remove(i_remove)
    else:
        print(f"Name not found: {new_removal}", file=sys.stderr)
```

One question you'll need to consider though is what to do if multiple names start with the same prefix.

For example, what if a user's contact list contains `Alex Balex`, and `Alex Ball`, and the user asks to remove `Alex Bal`?

The simplest solution here would be to simply not remove anything since the specific name of the contact cannot be deduced - but another option might be instead to prompt the user with the list of contacts with that prefix and ask them to choose which one they want to remove.

I leave this part to you - good luck!